# An interesting SQL query CHALLENGE - list the AVERAGE value of the top 3 scores of each athlete

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

```
An interesting SQL query CHALLENGE:

A table named athelets consisting of id, ath_id, name, score, date.

+----+--------+-----------------+--------+------------+
| id | ath_id | name            | record | r_date     |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |      2 | John Wayne      |     79 | 2010-07-08 |
|  2 |      7 | Ronald Regan    |     51 | 2000-03-22 |
|  3 |      1 | Ford Harrison   |     85 | 2009-11-13 |
|  4 |      2 | John Wayne      |     69 | 2017-01-01 |

Please write a sql query to list the average value of the top three scores of each athlete, something like:

ath_id: 1, the arithmetic mean of his/her top 3 records: 77
ath_id: 2, the arithmetic mean of his/her top 3 records: 73
ath_id: 3, the arithmetic mean of his/her top 3 records: 47
```

Comment: Some keywords for you to search for: group by, aggregate functions, limit and order by.

Comment: I know these "GROUP BY, AVG, limit, order by", but do not work. Any PRACTICAL and workable solution in MySQL query statement?

Comment: More 'ordinary' than 'interesting'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ath_id, avg(record)
   from 
     (select ath_id, record
       from atheletes as t1
        where 
        (select count(*) from atheletes  where t1.ath_id=ath_id and record > t1.record) < 3) as d
 group by ath_id;
```

The above query should works as expected.

Comment: Mr. Harshil, fantastic, you're my hero!

Just wonder how many years have you worked as db administrator or db user as an application developer?

Comment: That's very kind of you but honestly I'm a just a Fresher right now. Completed Masters in 2017.

Comment: BTW, you should accept it as answer and upvote it so that it can be helpful for the visitors in future.

Comment: Oh, a fresher completed master, PROMISING! I have upvoted it, haven't I? If not, tell me how to do it :-)

Comment: you may have upvoted it but it won't be displayed/count because you don't have enough reputation(15) to upvote. Hence, first accept it as answer and then upvote it.

Comment: Yes, I haven't enough scores(say, 15) so that I might not upvote it effectively. But good news is that I've accepted it as an answer. Thanks again, Mr. Harshil, "Great Expectations"!

Comment: My pleasure. Now you've enough rep to upvote any answer I guess. Anyways, if you want, you can share the link of your next questions (c, java or sql related) here to notify me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming combinations of athletes and records are unique...

```
SELECT ath_id
     , ROUND(AVG(record),2) top3_avg 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM athletes x 
         JOIN athletes y 
           ON y.ath_id = x.ath_id 
          AND y.record >= x.record 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) <=3
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY ath_id;
```